# Return different Layout based on user agent string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, user-agent

I have an application that needs to support both desktop and tablet browsing. Both versions will be significantly different, using different Layouts in `/Views/Shared/`

In the `Controller` I am currently reading the user agent string and returning different `Partial Views`, which are parsed within the one `Layout`. I want to have two different `Layouts`, one which gets rendered for tablets and one for desktop. Currently I have:

```
/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_HomeLayoutTablet.cshtml
```

How do I read the user agent string and have the server render the correct View before my own Controllers get called?

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3)

Comment: Thanks, had a look. I am currently using one View for Mobile and one for Desktop, using a different Layout for each. Since I am using PartialViews rendered within a <div> defined in the Layout, setting a Layout in the PartialViews causes a the Layout to be rendered twice; once normally, and again inside the <div> of the Layout. This is why I want to do away with this entirely and just display different Layouts from the onset, without referencing them in the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use mobile views and the contextcondition to return a different view, even for partials.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

From the examples in this post, if you wanted a view to be considered only for a mobile, you create 2 versions, one with the .mobile.cshtml extension.

Comment: This is currently what I am doing. All PartialViews are currently rendered within the same Layout regardless. The problem is that the Layout needs to be dramatically different for the desktop and mobile version. I need to add more information, going to create a new question.